# Fetch XML Using a Field Value

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

Can Fetch-XML for a sub-grid view be written to include a field value on the record?

I have a custom entity with a lookup to Account.
I would like to have a sub-grid of Cases related to that Account; the grid would show Cases related to the Account related to this custom entity instead of Cases related to the custom entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is possible, but is an unsupported customization.

You can find an example here: [Filter Sub-Grid Dynamics CRM 2011 Rollup 12 (Polaris)](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paul-nieuwelaars-blog/2013/01/24/filter-sub-grid-dynamics-crm-2011-rollup-12-%28polaris%29)

Pay attention to the rollup version of your crm environment.

Comment: I am getting the grid like this:                Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("accountcases")._control and changing the fetchXml like this                              grid.get_innerControl().SetParameter("fetchXml", fetch) where var fetch contains the new fetchXml. Is this supported? I am only using Xrm to access elements.

Comment: get_innerControl and SetParameter are unsupported methods. Maybe they will work forever, maybe not. Is necessary when a new rollup is out to check if the scripts are still working.